# Is there a Kill() command in python that doesn't kill blender as well?

Tags: python, scripting

Pretty simple but didn't see any viable solutions and couldn't come up with a *simple* one myself.

is there a kill() command in Blender that kills only the current script/process but doesn't also kill blender?

I'd rather not have to grab the process manually first then end it.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks in advanced.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/python-command-within-script-to-abort-without-killing-blender/56672#56672) You can interrupt an unresponsive script by pressing <kbd>ctl-C</kbd> in the system console. [Blender Tips and Tricks](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#use-the-terminal)

Comment: yeah but can I emulate that keypress within the system? then i could make my own kill() command except instead it'll be killprocc()