# Blender 3.2 will not quit when running in background

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

I have a windows batch file that calls blender to render various scenes & cameras in background. For some reason, blender.exe does not terminate at the end of the render and pass control back to the batch file.  I have to manually end the task in Task Manager for the job to continue.  The command I am using is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\blender.exe"  ^
  --debug --debug-gpu --debug-cycles  ^
  --background %blend_file%  ^
  --scene %scene_name%   ^
  -E CYCLES -s %frame_s%  -e %frame_e%   ^
  -o %output_path%   ^
  --python ".\python_temp\camera_setup.py"
```

The python script just sets the correct camera (there are several in the scene) and starts the animation:

```
import bpy 
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera_005 (Fly Thru)"]  
bpy.context.scene.render.use_multiview = False   
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True) 
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

The last few lines in the log file show blender unloading all the assets, so it's behaving as I would expect . . .  except it just sits there with 0% CPU and doesn't end?

I'd really appreciate any help . . .

Comment: I think the builtin python `quit()` will terminate the program

Comment: Thanks!  In the end, I used "import sys" followed by "sys.exit()" to force a close.  It seems really extreme, but it works for now.

Comment: yeah a lot of operators rely on some form of UI element to correctly work, I'm not surprised it didn't work. I suggest trying to always use lower-level API functions if you're going to run Blender headless. I guess you already saw this answer which suggests raising an Exception, which is ugly too but might suit your usecase more. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6784/86891